# My Raspberry pi server is connected to the wireless wifi, but cannot access to it from the internet

Tags: node.js, linux, networking, server, raspberry-pi3

I'm a newbie to linux and server. 
I bought a Raspberry pi 3 and configured it with Raspbian.
It's possible to access from a far away from my home where my pi is set through SSH or VNCViewer, but when I run a nodejs written server from my
pi, then it is not accessible from the browser.

I do this on my pi

$ node helloworld.js

and I access from the internet like this below

http://172.x.x.x:3000

(I set the port 3000 in nodejs)

I tried ping 172.x.x.x 
but didn't work

Can this problem be solved?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should check and see if the ports on your router/modem are open, specifically port 3000 in this case. SSH uses port 22 and regular web traffic uses port 80. A lot of times, ISPs or even just the default settings on routers will block access to higher ports like 3000.

Consider using a service such as: http://canyouseeme.org/  (this was just the first one I Googled, there might be better services)

Comment: I didn't check that yet, but it actually worked when I accessed through the localhost like ,

Comment: Yes but if it is the ISP blocking then using localhost wouldn't detect that since it's all internal traffic on your network. Additionally, routers can block the higher ports if it is external requests and leave them open to internal. Did the test give any results of blocking?

Comment: I solved the problem by accessing the server with the ip address of the router. Also the port forwarding problem was important matter too since it was necessary to be accessible for that router. Thanks !!